# WiFi protocol for Clavinova keyboards

Tags: wireless, keyboard, programming

Does anyone know anything about the protocol used for WiFi connections on Yamaha Clavinova 700 series?

There are iOS apps by Yamaha which can connect to the Clavinova via WiFi.  I'm curious what can be done over this protocol.

If I do a port scan on the Clavinova, it lists ports TCP 23 and 5555 as open.

Port 5555 is interesting.  When I connect to it, it'll immediately send the string "WAVE�U" (that is 0x574156458455).

When I connect to port 23, I get the string "start debug".

I somehow doubt that this protocol is only used over wifi though.

Does anyone have any leads to more information, protocol documentation, what can be done, etc?

Answer (score 1):

If you can dig up the service manual, there is a minute chance that they cover some of the technical aspects there.

If you have an iOS device with the app, you can document the consumer related functionality yourself: Capture the network traffic between the two devices as you go through the different app features.

You may use a sniffing tool such as [WireShark](https://www.wireshark.org) to capture the traffic. [This question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/41005/how-to-sniff-traffic-on-my-wireless-network) on security.SE explores that topic further.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers.  I was planning on sniffing and disassembling, but decided to ask a simple question first :)

Comment: Have you found out more about the Clavinova protocol?

Answer (score 0):

port 5555 seems an audio stream, you can see the data when the piano plays